# What's the meaning of Seq[Int] as a key in Map[Seq[Int], FactorNode]?

Tags: scala

I have the following line of code in Scala:

```
private val factorNodes: mutable.Map[Seq[Int], FactorNode] = mutable.Map[Seq[Int], FactorNode]()
```

So, this instantiates a `mutable.Map` but I don't understand the key -- `Seq[Int]`.

Is `Seq[Int]` an array of integers or just a special way of indexing to a position in the map?

Comment: In `scala` a `Seq` is much the same as a `List` implementation in Java.

Comment: If you want in-depth look in addition to the above comment of Christopher, visit this link http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/seqs.html

Comment: ok, so if I understand correctly, the key in the map is not a unique integer but a List of integers. I was not expecting that! Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Note that this is probably a poor design.  The hash-code will have to be computed on the Seq[Int] every time a lookup or insertion is performed, which could be bad for performance, plus it's just kind of odd/confusing to have a list of Ints as a key to a map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Seq[Int]` is a trait (similar to a Java interface). When implemented, it's basically an array of integers. This means that your map uses arrays as keys. You can do something like the following:

```
val a: FactorNode = new FactorNode
val b: FactorNode = new FactorNode

val map: mutable.Map[Seq[Int], FactorNode] = mutable.Map(Seq(1,2,3) -> a)

map += (Seq(1,2,5) -> b)

// and to retrieve:
map(Seq(4,5,6)) // should fail.
map(Seq(1,2,5)) // should return b.
```

Comment: "When implemented, it's basically an array of integers." No. It's _some_ kind of sequence of integers. It may not have efficient indexing or size operations, it may not be possible to change the elements, etc.

Comment: `Seq[Int]` is not a trait per se, `Seq` is, and yes, as Alexey pointed out **Seq is not array** (especially in java sense): underlying structure might be array list, linked list or something else, thus performance characteristics may vary significantly.